# Java Derby Creating User and "Schema Does Not Exist" Error

Tags: java, database-schema, derby, javadb

I am writing some archiving program in Java using derby DB. My program and DB connections (creating table, inserting and selecting data etc.) working fine when i use default user "APP" of Derby now.

When i try add some users and changing DB Properties, i can't connect to Database. I am sharing my User Creating and Changing DB Properties class below;

**Creating user and Setting DB Properties:**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

      Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby:sampleDB;user=APP;password=APP";
      Connection con = null;
      Statement stmt = null;

      con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
      stmt = con.createStatement();

      stmt.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");

      stmt.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.authentication.provider', 'BUILTIN')");

      stmt.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.user.testuser', 'ajaxj3x9')");

      stmt.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.fullAccessUsers', 'testuser')");

      stmt.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
            "'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'false')");

      stmt.close();

      con.close();


        boolean gotSQLExc = false;
        try {
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            if ( se.getSQLState().equals("XJ015") ) {
                gotSQLExc = true;
            }
        }
        if (!gotSQLExc) {
             System.out.println("Database did not shut down normally");
        } else {
             System.out.println("Database shut down normally");
        }



    }

}
```

After that when i use below statement to connect DB i receive `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'TESTUSER' does not exist` error

```
java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:derby:sampleDB;create=false;user=testuser;password=ajaxj3x9";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Also i have tried `CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION testuser` after all creating and properties defined in `CreateUser` class (sure i have rollback first creation proccess before trying this and run same Creating process after adding this line)  but when i try same statement i receive `TESTTABLE Schema Not Exist` error this time.

Comment: Your default schema is based on your username, so if you change your application to connect as a different user, and you don't explicitly specify which schema to use, you won't find your tables, as you'll be looking for table TESTUSER.TESTTABLE, but the database actually contains APP.TESTTABLE. Does that answer the question you're asking?

Comment: I read many articles about schema, authorization, creating user and privileges after my post. And you exactly right. TESTTABLE belongs to APP schema because it created with APP user. If i create new user, i can use APP.TESTTABLE in query when i want reach to table i know. But problem is i want restrict some users reachable to some table and some tables not. If i use APP.TESTTABLE in query every user can reach every table.

Comment: Restricting which tables can be accessed by which users is done via the GRANT statement: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevcsecuregrantrevokeaccess.html

Comment: After DB created with `APP`user and four tables created with `APP` user i have `APP.TESTTABLE1` `APP.TESTTABLE2` `APP.TESTTABLE3` `APP.TESTTABLE4`. After that, if i add some user to DB with `fullAccess`, all users should use `FROM APP.TESTTABLE1` in their `Select Statements`?

Comment: Yes, users can qualify their table access with the schema name, to be explicit about which table and schema are desired. There is also a SET SCHEMA statement: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html